# Return view from class with protocol

Tags: swift, swiftui

Iv created a protocol and some classes that use it

```
protocol Action {
    var title: String { get }

    associatedtype BodyView: View
    var body: BodyView { get }
}

class SomeAction: Action {
    var title: String = "Test Title"

    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
    }
}
```

In my normal view I now get a class that conforms to the protocol "Action" and should call the view of this class.

```
struct ActionSheet: View {
    @State var action: any Action
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            action.body

            .navigationTitle(action.title)
        }
    }
}

struct ActionSheet_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ActionSheet(action: SomeAction())
    }
}
```

But now I get the following error:

> Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'

If I just use "SomeView" as a type instead of "any Action" it works. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: SwiftUi doesn't work with existentials

Comment: https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/viewbuilder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`some View` requires a specific, known-at-compile-time concrete type that conforms to View. Your use of `any Action` seems to be trying to circumvent that. It cannot. You need to be able to prove at compile-time that the returned value of `ActionSheet.body` is a particular type.

Generally this would be addressed by making ActionSheet generic:

```
struct ActionSheet<A: Action>: View {
    @State var action: A
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            action.body

            .navigationTitle(action.title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm now i'm getting an error in the parent view "No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'". 

`
var test: [any Action] = [
   TestAction()
]

ForEach(test, id: \.title) { action in
 ActionSheet(action: action)
}`

Maybe what I'm trying to do is just dumb? All I want is a dynamic view depending on the Action in the array.

Comment: ForEach must know the type of every View at compile type. They cannot be dynamic. If they absolutely must be dynamic, that is what AnyView is for, but it has significant impacts on performance (which is why Apple pushes so hard to make all of these known at compile-time, so it can optimize them).

Comment: Typically you would use a `@ViewBuilder` for what you're describing, rather than an Array. See Adrian's link above.